# Using VMware as a server the host can connect to

Tags: sql-server-2012, vmware, windows-7-x64, windows-server-2012, vmware-workstation

I am attempting to connect to a SQL Server on a virtual machine (VMware) from the host.

The VM is running Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2012. The host is running Windows 7.

- I have changed the Network connection to Bridged (with and without the "Replicate physical network connection state" box checked), and Host-only.
- I have disabled/enabled the VMware Network Adapters VMnet1 and VMnet8.
- I have attempted to connect via the IP obtained from the VM, the adapters on the host, and by name.
- I have also attempted the above before/after restarting the VM.
- The firewall is off on the virtual machine.

I now have the urge to throw this computer out the window.

What I am finding online is just repeats of the above steps. Could someone explain to me how to do this as if I have never done something like this before (because I haven't), or failing that, tell me what I am doing wrong?

**Postscript:**

I am trying to make these questions as good as I can, but I am not very good at it. I have read the instructions for asking a good question a third time before asking this, and I am trying. So please, if you are going to mark it as unclear or a duplicate, please tell me why and give me a little time to alter it, or come back after I have had time to alter it, because it is very difficult to get better without feedback, and frustrating when people just say "this isn't a good question", put it on hold, and don't bother checking back when I try to make it better.

Comment: Can access (ping) your server from your workstation? If yes, have you enabled the sql server browser service? If yes, have you enabled TCP/IP in the configuration manager?

Comment: @Gabor : I can't ping the server by the IP provided by the virtual machine (ipconfig in powershell). SQL Server Browser is running, and TCP/IP is Enabled in the Protocols (as well as Shared Memory and Named Pipes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Bridged Networking** to communicate from host to VM guest OS, in your case Windows 7 to Windows 2012. Please refer [Understanding networking types in hosted products](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006480) for more information about VMware networking types.

Make sure to turn off firewall in Windows 2012 instance as it may block the network connectivity between two instances.

Comment: I have added additional detal to the question based on your post, thank you. Unfortunately, I have been using Bridged Networking, and the firewall is off.

Comment: Can you check whether win 2012 instance has an IP using `ipconfig` command. Also check `ipconfig` in win7 machine to verify vmnet adapters are not overlapping with win7 machine's network adapter IP range.

Comment: I have been using the ipconfig command in Windows Server 2012 to get the IP to ping for all my tests, so it does obtain an IP. The Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2, VMnet1, and VMnet8 all have different addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was that I didn't turn Windows Firewall all the way off, I just turned off the Domain Profile.

Once I turned off the Private and Public profiles as well, I was able to ping.

Thank you to those that offered their help. It is appreciated.